# Method not being triggered from razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, yui, razor, yui-datatable

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with the razor view engine.

I have the following method in my NewsController:

```
public JsonResult GetAllNews()
{
   var items = newsService.FindAll();
   var jsonResult = Json(items);

   return jsonResult;
}
```

In my view I want to try and call this method to populate my YUI datatable.  I put a breakpoint on the first line of this method but the breakpoint is not hit.  Here is my code in the view to call this method:

```
var newsDataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource('@Url.Action("GetAllNews");');
```

I even tried:

```
var newsDataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource("/News/GetAllNews/");
```

Both don't seem to work.

Here is my datatable code:

```
<div id="grdNews"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   // News grid
   var newsColumnDefs = [
      { key: "id", label: "Identifier" },
      { key: "title", label: "Title" },
      { key: "body", label: "Body" }
   ];

   //var newsDataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource('@Url.Action("GetAllNews");');
   var newsDataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource("/News/GetAllNews/");
   newsDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
   newsDataSource.responseSchema = {
      fields: [
         { key: "id" },
         { key: "title" },
         { key: "body" }
      ]
   };

   var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("grdNews", newsColumnDefs, newsDataSource);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to make this method return JSON for GET requests as well:

```
public JsonResult GetAllNews()
{
   var items = newsService.FindAll();
   return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also setting a [datasource](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/) doesn't mean that it will invoke the method. Maybe there's some other part of your code that's problematic. Install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see if an AJAX request is sent.

---

UPDATE:

Now that the question has been clarified and you are talking about YUI datatable, here's a full working example:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetAllNews()
    {
        var news = new[] 
        {
            new { id = 1, title = "title 1", body = "body 1" },
            new { id = 2, title = "title 2", body = "body 2" },
            new { id = 3, title = "title 3", body = "body 3" },
        };
        return Json(new
        {
            Result = news
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/fonts/fonts-min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/json/json-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/element/element-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datatable/datatable-min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var newsColumnDefs = [
        { key: "id", label: "Identifier" },
        { key: "title", label: "Title" },
        { key: "body", label: "Body" }
    ];

    var newsDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource('@Url.Action("GetAllNews")');
    newsDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
    newsDataSource.responseSchema = {
        resultsList: 'Result',
        fields: [ "id", "title", "body" ]
    };

    var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("grdNews", newsColumnDefs, newsDataSource); 
</script>

<div id="grdNews"></div>
```

Comment: @Darin: Thanks. What do I need to be on the look out for to if an AJAX request was sent?  What else do I need to setup on my app to get it working?

Comment: @Brendan, once you install FireBug you may look at the Console or the Net tab. All requests will be listed there. As far as to what you need to set, I cannot answer this question as you didn't even explain what you were trying to do. I would recommend you looking at the documentation and the multiple examples of YUI if this is what you intend to use. I think that your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. It's about how to use YUI.

Comment: @Darin: I'm trying to bring back news items and populate my datatable.  That's it.  I need to try and determine why my data is not being brought back.  That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Brendan, I would really recommend you going through the [YUI documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/). As I said the controller action is you've shown is perfectly fine (except the small remark about allowing GET requests which are disabled by default for JSON). I suspect the problem you are having is setting your YUI datatable but as you've shown no code about it I cannot say why it doesn't work. Also if you have problems setting YUI you might post another question specifically tagged to it as this no longer relates to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Darin: I agree with you that it is not a MVC issue.  But I am not going to open up a new post for that, we can work on this one then everybody knows everything about my scenario.  I updated my original post with the javascript code.

Comment: @Darin: It is debugging now. I forgot to add the json and connection javascript references :)